# asn.1 files for gsm map/inap

Tags: gsm, asn.1

I am looking for ASN.1 files for GSM-MAP and INAP protocols.  I tried to search in 3gpp.org but couldn't find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GSM MAP operations are detailed in 29.002, the corresponding asn1 file is available at following link
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/29_series/29.002/ASN.1/29002%207f0%20ASN1.zip

It is possible, that compiling above asn files identifies additional asn files - require another round of downloads from 3gpp.  For example, the supplementary services are detailed in 24.080 (link to download corresponding ASN.1 files follows).
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/24_series/24.080/ASN.1/24080-920%20ASN1.zip

For INAP, download the asn1 files for Q.1248 (zip file with all modules required to compile this recommendation) from ITU.  ITU download link below.

For CAMEL, download the 29.078 3gpp specification at following link, the asn text file is attached included in the archive.
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/29_series/29.078/29078-920.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you use INAP-CS1 (Capability Set 1), download ETS 300 374-1 protocol specification (http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_i_ets/300300_300399/30037401/01_60/ets_30037401e01p.pdf). This ETS is based on ITU-T Recommendation Q.1218 (1993) ("Interface Recommendation for intelligent network CS1"). This document is here https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-Q.1218-199303-S!!PDF-E&type=items . ASN.1 files for Q.1218 are here http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=3232&showfl=1